# How to use MSGraph programming API to check the list of signins for a service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I can use the Microsoft Graph programming API to review the sign-ins for all AAD users (including service principals).  It is a commonly used feature :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions

The average user is normally **disallowed** from using the API if they are not an admin. The exception to this rule is that a user can **check their own signins**.  Per the docs it states:

> Note: Azure AD users with any permissions can read sign-in logs in which their user is the actor signing in

Checking your own signins is accomplished by filtering on userId.  I'm trying to use this from a **service principal** to review its own signins like so:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns $filter=(userId eq '123792d1-b50f-4f7f-a8a3-40e0341e9e22')&$top=10

In the example above, the "userId" is the oid of the AAD service principal. However when I test this, the API keeps failing and preventing my service from checking on its own signins.  The error message says:

**"Calling principal does not have required MSGraph permissions AuditLog.Read.All"**

Can someone explain why AAD won't allow a service principal to review its own signins, as per the documentation?

Comment: "I'm trying to use this **from** a service principal" - what does that exactly mean? Who actually triggers API - is this the application? How do you authenticate in order to call Graph API?

Comment: What I mean is that the service principal is authenticating to AAD using oauth2 via the principal's client ID.  The authentication flow is confidential client, with a secret.  The scope is the one that reference graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/.default)

Answer (score 1):

I created an **Azure AD Application without granting any API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I tried to fetch the audit logs of the Service Principal, I got the **error** like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=(userId eq 'SPObjID')
```

[image]

**Note** that:

- According to the MsDoc, Any Azure AD user with the appropriate permissions has access to read sign-in logs where their user is the sign-in actor, but Service Principal have some exceptions and possibly not fall within this category.
- To establish an identity for sign-in and or to access resources, service principals are used.
- Access and permissions can be granted to service principals, but they cannot be directly updated or changed. Service principals are not among the users who have the ability to see sign-in logs where their user is the actor signing in.

Hence, to resolve the error, make sure to grant Admin consent to the **`AuditLog.Read.All`** API permission:

[image]

After assigning the API permission, **I am able to fetch the Audit logs successfully** like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get signIn - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: thanks for exploring this.  As you point out, Service Principal have some unusual exceptions; I think that is undocumented at best, and probably buggy.  Do you have links to explain diffs?  I've had lots of issues with service principals being throttled on AAD logins, and it makes sense to be able to monitor my own logins, without building a custom solution.  Granting AuditLog.Read.All is something that an admin is probably not willing to do, esp. since it has serious security implications and the Microsoft docs claim that users should *already* have access to their own signins.